Why is traffic not routing 100% to nginx-v2 in Istio VirtualService?
I just got into Istio to manage traffic for my nginx application. My goal is to route 100% of traffic to nginx-v2 and 0% to nginx-v1. Below are the steps I took and the configurations I applied:
deployments.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: quay.io/shardul/nginx:v1
          name: nginx-v1
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 80
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx-v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: quay.io/shardul/nginx:v2
          name: nginx-v2
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 80
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 80

service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx

istio components
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: default-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - "*"
      port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: nginx-dest-rule
spec:
  host: nginx
  subsets:
    - name: v1
      labels:
        version: v1
    - name: v2
      labels:
        version: v2
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-virtual-svc
spec:
  hosts:
    - nginx
  gateways:
    - istio-system/default-gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: nginx
            subset: v1
          weight: 0
        - destination:
            host: nginx
            subset: v2
          weight: 100

ran these commands:
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
istioctl install --set profile=default -y

Added AWS Load Balancer subnets to the Istio configuration:
annotations:
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet-0e278e208b0267781, subnet-057e2e3aba5f6ca2f"

Deployed the aws-load-balancer-controller using helm with correct permissions
Problem:
The traffic is still flowing to both nginx-v1 and nginx-v2. I want 100% traffic to go to nginx-v2 and 0% to nginx-v1.
What I've Tried:
Verified that nginx-v1 and nginx-v2 Pods have the correct labels (version: v1 and version: v2).
Confirmed that the DestinationRule and VirtualService are applied correctly.
Is there anything wrong with my Istio configuration (Gateway, DestinationRule, VirtualService)?
Could this be related to AWS Load Balancer or Istio IngressGateway misconfiguration?

I have replicated your setup and it worked fine for me

really? Only v2 returns a response?

Yes only responses from V2
